# Draw signals in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files

I am trying to typeset some examples of given signals using `tikz/pgf`. My initial thought was to plot them from ascii files using `pgfplots`. My code is the following

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=100:500,
    xmin=100, xmax=500,
    ymin=-260, ymax=40,
    axis lines=center,
    axis equal image,
    xlabel=$time$,
    ]
    \addplot[smooth] table {FINAL.dat}
        node[right] {$g(x)$};
    \addplot[color=blue, smooth] table {Single_Narrow.dat}
        node[above right] {$v(x)$};
    \addplot[color=red, smooth] table {Single_Medium.dat}
        node[above right] {$v(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the signals I have are not smoothed, as can be seen in the following picture

[image]

My questions are

1. Is there a way to smooth the plotted signals?
2. Can I generate such signals in `tikz/pgf`?

An editable copy of the project can be found in [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/17922566mrffrfqnfyvk).

Comment: Of course I do not know the content of your `.dat` files but I would guess that the issues are do to those, not pgfplots. And yes, you can draw such things with plain Ti*k*Z, just sometimes it is a bit more cumbersome to set the units by hand, and pgfplots has more built in features that allow you to tame large or very small numbers.

Comment: @marmot : Thank you very much for your comment. The `.dat` files can be seen in the link I provided, but I was thinking of generating "signals" with different rise times in `tikz/pgf`.

Comment: Which link? (I didn't see any dat files in the overleaf link, but I should add that I don't know anything about overleaf except that I made a very bad experience once answering a question where the code was in a overleaf project...)

Comment: You can also play with the `tension` parameter (pgfmanual v3.0.1a Section 22.8 p333) for the smoothing. When plotting data with high frequency content, I also modify the `line join` parameter. Initially, it is set to `miter` which gives sharp edges. You can try `bevel` or `round` (pgfmanual v3.0.1a Section 15.3.1 p167).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.dat` files in your Overleaf project have **a lot** of data points. You could add `each nth point=10, filter discard warning=false, unbounded coords=discard` to your `axis` options, this should make your plot a lot smoother. I've added markers so you can see which points are plotted.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=100:500,
    xmin=100, xmax=500,
    ymin=-260, ymax=40,
    axis lines=center,
    axis equal image,
    xlabel=$time$,
    each nth point=10, 
    filter discard warning=false, 
    unbounded coords=discard,
    ]
    \addplot[smooth,mark=x] table {FINAL.dat}
        node[right] {$g(x)$};
    \addplot[color=blue, smooth,each nth point=10,mark=x] table {Single_Narrow.dat}
        node[above right] {$v(x)$};
    \addplot[color=red, smooth,each nth point=10,mark=x] table {Single_Medium.dat}
        node[above right] {$v(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that this method will throw away data, so the very small crevice at approximately `x=300` will probably disappear. To counteract that, you can locally add some extra points, but you will have to plot multiple times. I only did this for the first plot, and added a legend because the nodes you draw are clipped away because they are drawn outside the `axis` region.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=100:500,
    xmin=100, xmax=500,
    ymin=-260, ymax=40,
    axis lines=center,
    axis equal image,
    xlabel=$time$,
    filter discard warning=false, 
    unbounded coords=discard,
    ]
    \addplot[smooth,each nth point=10,mark=x,restrict x to domain=100:290] table {FINAL.dat};
    \addplot[smooth,each nth point=1,mark=x,restrict x to domain=280:320,forget plot] table {FINAL.dat};
    \addplot[smooth,each nth point=10,mark=x,restrict x to domain=310:500,forget plot] table {FINAL.dat};
    \addlegendentry{\( g(x) \)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that the domains overlap, otherwise jumps will occur. The `forget plot` key is to prevent the second and third `\addplot` from showing up in the legend.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It was exactly what I was looking for!